# I need to place the button below relative to the text objective c

Tags: ios, viewlayout

I want to place the button lower relative the end of the text. How do I do this?
now so

[image]

Comment: What did you try? Are you using auto-layout? What are your constraints? What research have you done?

Comment: Does that text in label? Are you setting text dynamically?

Comment: Yes. now I measure the height of the text and respect thereto exhibit button. But I think it all has to be done much easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the `Height + Y` of your label as `Y value` in your button and it will display below your label.

```
yourLabel = your current text label....
yourButton.frame = CGRectMake(yourXValue, yourLabel.frame.origin.y + yourLabel.frame.size.height ,yourwidthValue, yourHeightValue);
```

Or use this code.. whichever you like

```
CGRect frame =yourButton.frame;
frame.origin.y = yourLabel.frame.origin.y + yourLabel.frame.size.height;
yourButton.frame = frame;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't place it relative to the text. However, it looks like the text is in a UILabel which will expand depending on how much text there is.

All you have to do is place the button relative to the bottom of the label and it will be placed below the text.